# How to select distinct rows where 2 columns should match on multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this :

```
id | user_id | param_id | param_value  
1      1          44          google
2      1          45         adTest
3      1          46         Campaign
4      1          47          null
5      1          48          null
6      2          44          google
7      2          45         adAnotherTest
8      2          46         Campaign2
9      2          47         null
10     2          48         null
```

I want to fetch all the user_ids where (param_id = 44 AND param_value=google) AND (param_id= 45 AND param_value = adTest) . So the above where clause should give only user_id = 1 and not user_id = 2 . They both have google at param_id 44 but only user 1 has param_value adTest at param_id = 45 .

The problem is the n the future more params could be added . I need to find a dynamic query . Here what i have tryed :

```
SELECT DISTINCT up.user_id FROM user_params AS up

                    LEFT JOIN user_params AS upp ON up.id = upp.id

                    WHERE up.param_id IN (?,?) 

                    AND upp.param_value IN (?,?)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT up.user_id 
FROM user_params AS up
LEFT JOIN user_params AS upp ON up.id = upp.id
group by up.user_id
having sum(param_id = 44 AND param_value = 'google') >= 1
and sum(param_id = 45 AND param_value = 'adTest') >= 1
```

Comment: Ty for the fast answer , briliant

Comment: Nice +1 and posted an upgrade based on your answer

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
SELECT  -- DISTINCT 
    up1.user_id 
FROM 
    user_params AS up1
  JOIN
    user_params AS up2 
      ON up1.user_id = up2.user_id
WHERE
    up1.param_id = 44 AND up1.param_value = 'google'
  AND 
    up2.param_id = 45 AND up2.param_value = 'adTest' ;
```

You do not need the `DISTINCT`, if there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(user_id, param_id)`

For efficiency, add an index on `(param_id, param_value, user_id)`

---

The problem you are dealing with is called "Relational Division" and there is a great answer by @Erwin Brandstetter here: **[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)**, with a lot of ways to write such a query, along with performance tests.

The tests were done in Postgres so some of the queries do not even run in MySQL but at least half of them do run and efficiency would be similar in many of them.

Comment: Distinct was removed :) , ty for the notice . But you answer is not that efficient at all because the query is dynamic like i said in the question . If i add more and more joins will not be a good solution . The accepted solution is the best for a dynamic query (many param_id param value pairs to be matched)

Comment: It may not be good because you have to build a different query every time, so it requires a dynamic solution. But have you really tested efficiency or you are just guessing? My estimate is that the more the joins, the more efficient this query gets.

Comment: When was a query with 12++ joins efficient ? :)

Comment: See this (7-join): **[Subqueries run very fast individually, but when joined are very slow](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31828/subqueries-run-very-fast-individually-but-when-joined-are-very-slow/31836#31836)**. From 400 seconds down to 0.0318 seconds, with proper indexing.

Comment: When you join the same table , isn't the mysql engine reading all the data all over again ? Isn't it better to read it only once or fewer times if possible ?

Comment: That's why I suggested that index. It will only have to read from the index (and only a small part of it, for every one of the joins.)

Comment: But still won't be an indexed 1 time read be better than 12x times indexed read ? :) The index is added btw :)

Comment: Yes, but the other queries will have to read (much) larger parts of the index and also have to do the GROUP BY and aggregate calculations. This query will do an intersection of the (2 or more)  `user_id` lists found by the index seeks. It really depends on the distribution of your data and for some cases the GROUP BY solution will be better and in other cases the JOIN method. It doesn't hurt to test in your environment with your data - and choose the best for you.

Comment: I really can't say about mysql's performance regarding group by or aggregate functions . But i think the above query can be edited by doing simple (param_id = 44 AND param_value = 'google') which should return true or false . No agregate needed

Comment: Anyway the problem was not the performance of the query :) Ty for the help and for the link . I will read it to view some real examples and benchmarks

Comment: Which one do you mean can be edited? Both the other answers have `GROUP BY` and `HAVING SUM(..) `. I don't see how they can be edited.

Comment: sum(true and true)>=1 is the same as (true and true) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize this should give the same results without the need an LEFT JOIN  table scans (**thanks to juergen d for having part**)

```
SELECT
 user_id

FROM 
 user_params

WHERE
  param_id IN(44, 45)
 AND
  param_value IN('google', 'adTest')

GROUP BY
 user_id 

HAVING 
    sum(param_id = 44 AND param_value = 'google') >= 1
  AND
    sum(param_id = 45 AND param_value = 'adTest') >= 1
;
```

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17b65/4 for demo